# 4-Digit number conversion to Date [Excel]

Tags: excel, api

I'm facing an issue when I receive a **4-digit** value from an API in `Excel` data.

For the following value, `8324`, it is supposed to be May 24, 2023.

I've tried formatting this with the Excel format tool, but nothing. Anyone know how I can convert that?

Thanks.

--- Update ----

I've noticed that somewhere before filling the value the string of numbers was split letting 4 digits at the end.

Thanks for your help here.

Comment: `May 24, 2023` equivalent number values would be `45070`.

Comment: Excelo has a serial number for may 24 which is 45070. How does your number work?

Comment: What are the API spec's for translating a 4 digit number into a 5-8digit date?

Comment: You will have to tell us how your date API actually works, but if each day is the previous day's integer plus one, then its calendar base is 8/8/2000.  If so then adding 36746 to the API date will turn it into an EXCEL date.  (=45070 - 8324)

Answer (score -1):

Add 36746.

In Excel, dates are numbers too, but Excel and your API have different horizon dates.

45070 - 8324 = 36746 so to convert you just need to add 36746 to the numbers you get from your API.